# How can I parse html elements in php?

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I need get content of few html elements from html file in php. 
The elements are:

- title
- meta keywords
- meta description
- h1

It's posible that you have title twice, three-times, ... on the page, I need all occurrence => $array_of_titles
Same for other tags. 
I need collect this data for checking duplicity of tags on page.

**I've tryed this:**

- DOMDOCUMENT + DOMXPATH => work only on well formed html => unusable in real world there are too many mof*s who are not able to write valid html
- Simple Html DOM Parser - failed this library is full of bugs

What can I do? It looks as really trivial problem but ...

Comment: Go crazy with regular expressions :)

Comment: @dan08 its bad practise use regexp for this

Comment: Show us your DOM testing and we can probably help you.

Comment: It works on my testing DOM, but it should work on every DOM :/
I don't have any specification of input, I just go throught sitemap and parse html pages one by one. DOMDocument works on my testing case, but if you forgot somewhere in the html " or / at ending of some other tag, domdocument fails

Comment: @greg_diesel there is how I do it with DomDocument, working only on wellformed html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263929/parsing-html-with-domdocument-and-xpath-fail-in-php

Comment: Can you run the html through a library to clean it up and make it well formed first?

Comment: @developerwjk No I can't. I don't know how. What library? Any experiences?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of parsers I know of off-hand which will work with invalid HTML:

1. [PHP Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
2. [Ganon](https://code.google.com/p/ganon/)

As someone else has stated, regular expressions are absolutely *not* the way to go. Save your hair and your sanity, and don't go down that road.

Comment: I've mentioned PHP Simple Dom in my question - doesn't work for my problem - has unresolved bugs, but I'll try Ganon

Comment: You might give `phpQuery` a shot, too. I'm not sure how well it will do with invalid HTML, but I've used it in a couple of previous projects without any problem.

https://github.com/soloproyectos/phpquery

Comment: I've tried phpQuery, but I have problems with this: `include_once("phpQuery-onefile.php");
   $pq = phpQuery::newDocumentFile($file_url);
   print var_dump($pq->find("h1")->text());`
Find gives me ONE string with values separated by SPACES, which is not so clever, I could explode it by spaces, but you know what happens when in the element content is space => I need have output of find in some array and I think its probably not possible or is it?

Comment: Sorry I used another phpQuery I used the google one: https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/
I will try yours too

Comment: They're the same project. The github version might be slightly more up to date, though; I'm not sure. As for using `find`, it should return a list of nodes. Rather than just using `text` right afterward, iterate over the list.